# ES6 for of statement error even when compiled with babel

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm having some issues working out what is wrong with this statement.

```
for(const form of doc.getElementsByClassName('class-name')) { .... }
```

Looking at the [compatibility listings](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#for..of_loops) for this I can see why it is having issues with running in plain ES6 on safari given it has no support. However this is till occurring when I compile the ES6 with babel.

When compiled I get the following:

```
var _iteratorNormalCompletion3 = true;
    var _didIteratorError3 = false;
    var _iteratorError3 = undefined;

    try {
        for (var _iterator3 = doc.getElementsByClassName('class-name')[Symbol.iterator](), _step3; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion3 = (_step3 = _iterator3.next()).done); _iteratorNormalCompletion3 = true) {
            var form = _step3.value;
        }
    } catch (err) {
        _didIteratorError3 = true;
        _iteratorError3 = err;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (!_iteratorNormalCompletion3 && _iterator3.return) {
                _iterator3.return();
            }
        } finally {
            if (_didIteratorError3) {
                throw _iteratorError3;
            }
        }
    }
```

But this triggers an error in safari

```
TypeError: doc.getElementsByClassName('class-name')[Symbol.iterator] is not a function. (In 'doc.getElementsByClassName('class-name')[Symbol.iterator]()', 'doc.getElementsByClassName('class-name')[Symbol.iterator]' is undefined)
```

This is using the latest version of Babel, compiled with gulp through browserify and babelify all the latest versions. If i install the `transform-es2015-for-of` plugin and force it on I get the following result:

```
var _loop = function _loop() { };

    for (var _iterator2 = doc.getElementsByClassName('class-name'), _isArray2 = Array.isArray(_iterator2), _i2 = 0, _iterator2 = _isArray2 ? _iterator2 : _iterator2[Symbol.iterator]();;) {
        var _ref2;

        var _ret = _loop();

        if (_ret === 'break') break;
    }
```

But this gives me another safari error:

```
TypeError: _iterator2[Symbol.iterator] is not a function. (In '_iterator2[Symbol.iterator]()', '_iterator2[Symbol.iterator]' is undefined)
```

Comment: Is your `doc` variable set with `document`?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/iterators-polyfill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate over a NodeList , the NodeList needs to have a `Symbol.iterator` property but babel does not polyfill the DOM, only JS.

I would recommend no to use `for of` altogether, or use a HTML5 DOM polyfill in addition to babel to make it work.

https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/545

Comment: I'm amazed Safari still doesn't support this, a easy clean way to loop classes is pretty much the only reason I'd want to use jQuery.

What would be the best alternative to a for of in that situation?

Comment: @chris just add the polyfill. `NodeList[Symbol.iterator] = [][Symbol.iterator];` and it works.

Comment: I got this working with babel-polyfill then wit corejs's much smaller much more flexible polyfill. I now await the next issue to crop out of nowhere.